# Solr: Using spellchecker with advanced solr schema

Tags: solr

I trying improve spellchecker behavior on my project.

I do spellchecking only on one field("title"). Related configs at the bottom.

Reason if this configs - support objects with special chars.

e.g. :
 - Angry wars: T70, the best world tank!
 - Modern chipset M74K34#11$$1
 - A:B:C
 - 100500bestprices!!!very-cool-object|title

to cover most cases I use configured "solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" filter.

**Problem**:  in spellchecker results: when I try to search "angr birds" I receive "angry birds:" instead expected "angry birds". Possible, will be enough just trim keywords by spec chars( I mean to split "Angry wars: T70," => "angry", "wars", "T70", "T", "70" ). But how I can trim keywords by spec chars ? Or anyone have better ideas?

```
<field name="title" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

where "text_en" is:

```
<fieldType name="text_en" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0" splitOnNumerics="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.KStemFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In SolrConfig I use

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="spellcheck.count">3</str>
   <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">default</str>
   <str name="spellcheck.dictionary">wordbreak</str> <!-- index -->

   <str name="spellcheck.maxCollationTries">10</str>
   <str name="spellcheck.maxCollations">5</str> 
</lst>
<arr name="last-components">
     <str>spellcheck</str>
</arr>
</requestHandler>


<searchComponent name="spellcheck" class="solr.SpellCheckComponent">

<str name="queryAnalyzerFieldType">textSpell</str>
  <lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">default</str>
  <str name="field">title</str>
  <!-- <str name="field">default_search_field</str> -->
  <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str>
  <!-- the spellcheck distance measure used, the default is the internal levenshtein -->
  <!-- <str name="distanceMeasure">internal</str> -->
  <str name="distanceMeasure">org.apache.lucene.search.spell.JaroWinklerDistance</str>

  <!-- minimum accuracy needed to be considered a valid spellcheck suggestion -->
  <float name="accuracy">0.7</float>
  <!-- the maximum #edits we consider when enumerating terms: can be 1 or 2 -->
  <int name="maxEdits">2</int>
  <!-- the minimum shared prefix when enumerating terms -->
  <int name="minPrefix">1</int>
  <!-- maximum number of inspections per result. -->
  <int name="maxInspections">5</int>
  <!-- minimum length of a query term to be considered for correction -->
  <int name="minQueryLength">4</int>
  <!-- maximum threshold of documents a query term can appear to be considered for correction -->
  <float name="maxQueryFrequency">0.01</float>
  <!-- uncomment this to require suggestions to occur in 1% of the documents
    <float name="thresholdTokenFrequency">.01</float>
  -->      
  <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
  <str name="buildOnOptimize">true</str>
  <str name="combineWords">true</str>
  <str name="breakWords">true</str>
  <str name="comparatorClass">freq</str>
  <str name="collate">true</str>
  <str name="count">5</str>
</lst>

<lst name="spellchecker">
  <str name="name">wordbreak</str>
  <!-- <str name="classname">solr.DirectSolrSpellChecker</str> -->
  <str name="classname">solr.WordBreakSolrSpellChecker</str>
  <str name="field">title</str>
  <str name="combineWords">true</str>
  <str name="breakWords">true</str>
  <int name="maxChanges">5</int>
</lst>

</searchComponent>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control the characters you want removed

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(:)" replacement=" " replace="all"/>
```

Comment: but this remove(split) all ':' chars, but i this i need remove just trailing chars.  is it possible ? // or maybe with regexp ?

Comment: Make a different field for spellcheck. Index clean terms for spellcheck in that field and use it for spellcheck. Search with text_en field. And yes with regex you can also just remove trailing chars.